# Dynamically change javascript code from HTML page

Tags: javascript

I have a site that show ads.

These ads are JavaScript snippets given by the ads provider.

I'd like to know whether it's possible to automatically replace the JavaScript snippet of these ads in my page by another JavaScript snippet to show ads from other ad provider after some time user is browsing the page (say 1 minute).

I looked for a solution but I failed to find one.

So a practical example:

How to change the code below

```
<div id="myAd">
    <div id="headbanner"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2874724721134868";
        /* girlsgamesalon-468x60 */
        google_ad_slot = "4183777947";
        google_ad_width = 468;
        google_ad_height = 60;
        //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

by

```
<div id="myAd">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='http://advertising.youraddprovider.com/ad/getoffers/?instanceID=xx18fdbb471&" + Math.random() + "'></scri" + "pt>");</script>
</div>
```

after 1 minute that user is browsing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is impossible to change the javascript code. You have to haldle that with server side code, like php, c#.net, etc, etc.

Example in php:

```
if(someconditionismet)
{
echo "<script src='thejsfileforthiscase.js'></script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script src='theotherjsfile.js'></script>";
}
```

**Update asked for the user:**

You could use

`document.write("<script src='javascriptfile.sj'></script>")`

But it will delete the whole content of you page which mean that if you a html tag, document.write will delete and will write just the tags. There is a work around but as i told you, `DO NOT USE IT`.

And with server side, you have to learn php, or c#.net, asp.net, etc, etc. I already answered you. If you want i can give you some good toturials to start.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wasn't aware of that. I'm not a JavaScript developer but I thought that by means of JSONP it would be possible.

Comment: There is a way with javascript but i can tell you that you should never use it. May bring alots of problems. Server side is the best idea :D

Comment: Could you share both how to do it and what problems its use can bring?

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's not a problem for me to program in PHP. I Prefer to do it on client side because I want to change the code for the same user seeing the page without the need to another call to server-side.